# Changing a JComboBox model unsing a ListModel. Does it have hidden consecuences?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcombobox

I use both JList and JComboBox in different places. The content of both change dynamically.

Once a comboBox is created you cant just say comboBox.setModel(String[]), you have to create a new model and then set it to the comboBox.

Same happens with the JList.

Rather than creating my own Jlist and ComboBox just to add a new method called .setNewModel(String[]) i created a static method in my "utility" class that receives a String[] and returns a ListModel.

So i can do this:

```
someComboBox.setModel((ComboBoxModel)UtilityClass.convetToListModel(aStringArray));
```

I use the same for the JList.

```
someList.setModel(UtilityClass.convetToListModel(anotherStringArray));
```

my question is:

Could the casting of the listModel as a ComboBoxModel have some unexpected consequences?
If so, is there anyway to change the entire content of a comboBox without having to transform the ArrayString into a Model?

here is the code of the method:

```
public static ListModel convertToListModel(String[] nList)
{
    return (new JComboBox(nList).getModel());
}
```

The program compiles and runs fine, but casting always generates doubts in me, specially complex objects.
Yes i know i can extend JComboBox and JList to add a method that does the job but its a lot of extra work. Why the ComboBox and Jlist don't have a update or modify Model than accept a simple array of Strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is

```
someComboBox.setModel((ComboBoxModel)UtilityClass.convetToListModel(aStringArray));
```

in any way easier to write/simpler/whatever than

```
someComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(aStringArray))
```

all you added is white noise in the form of the Utility method. Plus

- the implementation of that method is simply ... crazy: you create a *JComboBox* just for the sake of accessing the model that's internally created by that combo ...
- you have to exploit implementation to type-cast for usage in a real combo ...

Don't do such wasteful/unnecessary stuff, don't even think of going any detours when there's a simple straightforward manner to reach the same goal

Comment: Thanks. I Totally overlook this defaultComboBoxModel. The first thing i tried was almost exactly that but with ComboBoxModel, got error that it was abstract and did all that (now) crazy workaround. Cleaning up code right now.

Answer (score 3):

If the contents of the list/combobox need to change dynamically, then you should manage the model itself directly. You shouldn't create a new model each time and replace the old one. The whole point of having a model is that you can update the data it contains.

Simply create your own `DefaultListModel` or `DefaultComboBoxModel` and pass it into the JList/JComboBox. Then use the model's add/remove methods as needed to update the contents when it changes.

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(model);
...

model.addElement(somethingForMyList);
...
model.removeAllElements();
...
model.removeElement(elementToRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would mean adding one element at a time using a loop to read the array, witch i didn't want to do. Thats why i posted the question, i knew that an easier way had to exist but didn't do the right search. Again thanks.

Comment: It's quite strange as when you set the model, it's an instance of `DefaultComboBoxModel`, but when you do `combo.getModel()`, it's an instance of `ComboBoxModel` and you cannot just `addElement(e)`. I guess it's protected right?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would prefer to implement a new class that is inherited from [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) (therefore it's also a [ListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) as well as a [ComboBoxModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html)). This new class would be enriched with methods to update the model as any possible situation demands. In the update methods you would call [fireContentsChanged](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to tell the enclosing component that the contents have changed and the component should redraw everything.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That would be overkill and exactly what i wanted to avoid, since I don't need any extra functionality, all my problems steered from the lack of a direct way to set my arrayString in the model in a single step. defaultComboBoxModel resolves it. Ignorance eat me.